# Google Analytics API - RemarketingAudiences.insert only working when linkedAdAccounts is AD_WORDS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm writing a Google Apps Script for creating audiences in Google Analytics. I keep getting the very unhelpful error message of `There was an internal error.`

As per [this guide][1], I am able to insert new audiences with the type `AD_WORDS` without issue. However my current task involves duplicating audiences of type `ANALYTICS`.

It seems that the `linkedAdAccounts` attribute of the resource I submit is incorrect. I can see that the official docs mention 3 possible options for the `type`: `ADWORDS_LINKS`, `DBM_LINKS`, `MCC_LINKS` or `OPTIMIZE`. Unfortunately, no detailed explanation is given for how these work other than `ADWORDS_LINKS`.

Here is the payload which is being rejected:

```
{
    name: "newName",
    linkedViews: ["123445677"],
    linkedAdAccounts: [
      {
        kind: "analytics#linkedForeignAccount",
        internalWebPropertyId: "12345678",
        status: "OPEN",
        remarketingAudienceId: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        webPropertyId: "UA-1234567-1",
        type: "ANALYTICS",
        accountId: "12345678",
      },
    ],
    audienceType: "SIMPLE",
    audienceDefinition: {
      includeConditions: {
        daysToLookBack: 7,
        segment: "users::condition::ga:sessionDuration>60",
        membershipDurationDays: 30,
        isSmartList: false,
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can't add an id for an `ANALYTICS` `linkedAdAccount`. Just adding the following is sufficient.

```
linkedAdAccounts: [
      {
        type: "ANALYTICS",
      },
    ],
```